# Filter Tensorflow Dataset according to model prediction

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to filter a TensorFlow dataset by selecting only samples that are correctly predicted by a trained model. Dataset is made of image,label pairs. I've tried this:

```
predicted_labels = np.argmax(model.predict(dataset), axis=1)
predicted_labels_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(predicted_labels)
zipped_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset, predicted_labels_dataset))
correct_dataset = zipped_dataset.filter(lambda sample, predicted_label: tf.math.equal(x = predicted_label, y = sample[1]))
```

But it does not work as expected. I still get wrongly classified samples in the `correct_dataset`. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

THe only reason I can think of this not working is that, your `sample[1]` does not represent the label (or not in the correct format). I ran the following toy example and worked fine. Happy to refine the answer depending on your follow ups until we identify the exact problem.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


predicted_labels_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([0,1,2,1,2,3])

inp_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.random.normal(shape=[6,5]))
lbl_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1,1,0,0,2,3])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((inp_ds, lbl_ds))
zipped_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset, predicted_labels_dataset))

correct_dataset = zipped_dataset.filter(lambda sample, predicted_label: tf.math.equal(x = predicted_label, y = sample[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think the problem is actually with the keras mode.predict(). It seems like that running it on batches return different labels than running it without batches. Do you have any advice?