# Filter Tensorflow dataset by id

Tags: python, tensorflow

**ISSUE**

I'm trying to filter a Tensorflow 2.4 dataset based on a numpy array containing the indices that I wish to subset. The dataset has 1000 images of shape (28,28,1).

**TOY EXAMPLE CODE**

```
m_X_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list(range(1, 21))).shuffle(10, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
arr = np.array([3, 4, 5])
m_X_ds = tf.gather(m_X_ds, arr)  # This is the offending code
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<ShuffleDataset shapes: (), types: tf.int32>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.ShuffleDataset'>) to a Tensor.
```

**RESEARCH SO FAR**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125266/how-do-i-split-tensorflow-datasets) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214002/filter-tensorflow-dataset-according-to-model-prediction) but they are specific to their use-cases while I'm looking for a more general way to subset (i.e. based on an externally-derived array of indices).

I'm very new to Tensorflow datasets and to-date have found the learning curve quite steep. Hope to get some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### TL;DR

It is recommended to use Option C, defined below.

#### Full answer

The `tf.data.Dataset` object is created so that all the objects don't have to be loaded into memory. Becuase of that, using `tf.gather` is not going to work by default. There are three options you can go with:

#### Option A: Load ds into memory + tf.gather

If you wanted to use gather you would have to load the entire dataset into memory, and select a subset:

```py
m_X_ds = list(m_X_ds)  # Load into memory.
m_X_ds = tf.gather(m_X_ds, arr))  # Gather as usual.
print(m_X_ds)  
# Example result: <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([8, 6, 2], dtype=int32)>
```

Note, that this is not always possible, especially with huge datasets.

#### Option B: Iterate over the dataset, and filter undesired samples

You could also iterate over the dataset and manually choose the samples with desired index. This would be possible via combination of [filter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter) and [tf.py_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function)

```py
m_X_ds = m_X_ds.enumerate()  # Create index,value pairs in the dataset.

# Create filter function:
def filter_fn(idx, value):
    return idx in arr

# The above is not going to work in graph mode
# We are wrapping it with py_function to execute it eagerly
def py_function_filter(idx, value):
    return tf.py_function(filter_fn, (idx, value), tf.bool)

# Filter the dataset as usual:
filtered_ds = m_X_ds.filter(py_function_filter)
```

#### Option C: combine option B with tf.lookup.StaticHashTable

Option B is good apart from the fact that you can expect a performance hit when converting graph tensor -> eager tensor -> graph tensor. `tf.py_function` is useful but at a cost.

Instead, we could declare a dictionary where desired indices would return true and non present indices could return false. This dict could look like this

```py
my_table = {3: True, 4: True, 5: True}.
```

We cannot use tensor as dictionary key, but we can declare a [tensorflow's hash table](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lookup/StaticHashTable) to let us check for "good" indices.

```py
m_X_ds = m_X_ds.enumerate()  # Do not repeat this if executed in Option B.

keys_tensor = tf.constant(arr)
vals_tensor = tf.ones_like(keys_tensor)  # Ones will be casted to True.

table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
    tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys_tensor, vals_tensor),
    default_value=0)  # If index not in table, return 0.


def hash_table_filter(index, value):
    table_value = table.lookup(index)  # 1 if index in arr, else 0.
    index_in_arr =  tf.cast(table_value, tf.bool) # 1 -> True, 0 -> False
    return index_in_arr

filtered_ds = m_X_ds.filter(hash_table_filter)
```

Regardless of Option B or C, all there is left is to drop the index from your fileterd dataset. We can use simple map, with lambda function:

```py
final_ds = filtered_ds.map(lambda idx,value: value)
for entry in final_ds:
    print(entry)

# tf.Tensor(7, shape=(), dtype=int32)
# tf.Tensor(13, shape=(), dtype=int32)
# tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and detailed explanation! I wish the TF documentation is as simple and clear. One more thing: For Option B, could you show me how to get a dataset _without_ all the first elements (IDs) in every tuple? I intend to use the filtered dataset for training.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, the resulting dataset should comprise just the filtered 3 tensors with shape (28,28,1).

Comment: Thank you for kind words. I edited my answer to include dropping the index, and third solution for the problem. All the best!

Comment: Hi @sebastian-sz, sorry to trouble you again but when I tried to implement Option C, the line `filtered_ds = m_X_ds.filter(hash_table_filter)` gave an error: `ValueError: 'predicate' return type must be convertible to a scalar boolean tensor. Was NoneTensorSpec().` Even using my toy example code + Option C didn't work. Would you kindly help?

Comment: If it matters, I'm using TF v2.4

Comment: My apologies, the function `hash_table_filter` was missing a return statement (hence the None error). I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to 'rescue' me! I've tested Option B and C and both work fine, the only difference being the speed. During my tests, Option B couldn't utilise more than 30% of my Tesla T4 while Option C can use nearly 100% consistently. So you're right - use Option C.

Comment: Glad that Option C works for you! Also, that's an interesting benchmark. I will keep in mind that `tf.py_function` performance penalty is quite large.