# How to write a few-shot filter for tensorflow datasets?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Is there any way to write a `tfds.Dataset.filter` function that filters out 5 images per class?

I've tried to create an object (and also an equivalent function) with an attribute to keep track of the classes. `filter()` accepts this as input and also runs through the code, but it just does not count the classes.

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

class few_shot_filter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = {}

    def filter(self, x):
        y = x["label"]
        if not y in self.count:
            self.count[y] = 0
        self.count[y] = self.count[y] + 1
        return self.count[y] <= 5

ds = tfds.load("cifar10", supervised=False)
fs_filter=few_shot_filter()
print([y["label"] for y in ds.filter(fs_filter.filter).as_numpy_iterator()])
```

Funnily, handing over an object and accessing its attribute in general does not seem to be a problem, since the code below works perfectly fine. Is the filter applied in parallel or so, like in array indexing?

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

class class_filter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.target_class = 5

    def filter(self, x):
        y = x["label"]
        return y == self.target_class

ds = tfds.load("cifar10", supervised=False)
fs_filter=class_filter()
print([y["label"] for y in ds.filter(cl_filter.filter).as_numpy_iterator()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround. Iterate over the dataset, save indices we want to keep, define a constant list of indices to keep, and hand that over to the filter. Follows [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411957/22729928).

```
# Give unique indices to dataset
ds = ds.enumerate()

# Find few-shot indices we want to keep
class_count = {}
selected_idxes = []
for idx, x in ds.as_numpy_iterator():
    y = x["label"]
    if y not in class_count:
        class_count[y] = 0
    if class_count[y] < self.n_few_shot:
        selected_idxes.append(idx)
        class_count[y] = class_count[y] + 1
keys_tensor = tf.constant(selected_idxes)
vals_tensor = tf.ones_like(keys_tensor)
table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
    tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys_tensor, vals_tensor),
    default_value=0)  # If index not in table, return 0.

# create a filter that accesses the constant (!) hashtable
def hash_table_filter(index, value):
    table_value = table.lookup(tf.cast(index, tf.int32))  # 1 if index in arr, else 0.
    index_in_arr = tf.cast(table_value, tf.bool)  # 1 -> True, 0 -> False
    return index_in_arr
ds = ds.filter(hash_table_filter)

# Remove the index
ds = ds.map(lambda idx, value: value)  # drop index

print([y["label"] for y in ds.as_numpy_iterator()])
```